# Tornado server stuck in loop, not accepting clients

Tags: python, stream, websocket, tornado, infinite

I've written a code in tornado that connects to a server that is pushing an infinite data stream, processes the data stream and sends it out on a websocket server.
The problem is that the way I implemented it the server became blocked on a particular function and doesn't accept any more clients since it never exits the function serving the data to the websocket. I want the connection to the server and the data retrieved from it processed only once but send the processed data to all the clients that connect to my tornado server. Could someone please help me, I can't figure out a way to do it. Here's my code with processing of data removed:

```
import socket
import ssl
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

websockets = []

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):


  def readData(self):
    while True:
        line = self.ssl_sock.read()

        #PROCESS THE READ LINE AND CONVERT INTO RESULTING DATA


        if(toSend):
                self.write_message(result)

  def makeConnection(self):
      self.ssl_sock.connect(self.address)
      self.readData()



  def open(self):
    print 'New connection was opened'
    self.s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.ssl_sock=ssl.wrap_socket(self.s, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
    self.address=('SERVER_ADDRESS',5000)
    self.nodes=[]
    self.edges=[]
    if self not in websockets:
        print ('added')
        websockets.append(self)

    if(len(websockets)==1):
        print('executing make conn')
        self.makeConnection()
    else:
        self.readData()
        print('executing read data')


  def on_message(self, message):
    print 'Incoming message:', message
    self.write_message("You said: " + message)

  def on_close(self):
    print 'Connection was closed...'


application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":

  http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
  http_server.listen(8888)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: I read the example you sent. I don't get it completely. How is the guy connecting to the API and getting the data?

Comment: He's storing all the clients that have connected in the `cl` list.  Whenever the `api` method is called, he can process the data there, then loop through all the clients connected to the server `cl` and send a response to all of them, is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I got that. In my case I am connecting to my TLS Server that constantly gives out a data stream that is processed and sent out through this webSocket handler. In my case how am I supposed to call the function that reads and processes the data infinitely without blocking the server?

Answer (score 0):

Tornado is an asynchronous framework, that is, all your IO must be run within its event loop, otherwise the whole server gets stuck.

Try having a look at [Tornado Async Client](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html).